# mySQL query for building dynamically populated model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo, model

I have some code below which demonstrates a hard-coded example of what I would like to accomplish dynamically.

At a high level, I wish to do something like `select * from view_data_$app_state` and then get all of the data from that views table into my mustache templates dynamically.

The code I currently must use to group multiple rows of data for a specific column along with the views data is:

```
 <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class Example {
        function __construct(){
            try {
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Example', 'root','drowssap');
            } 
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                print($e->getMessage());
                die();
            }
        }
        function __destruct(){
            $this->db = null;
        }
        function string_to_array($links_string){
            return explode(",", $links_string);

        }
        function get_view_data(){
            $q = $this->db->prepare('select *, GROUP_CONCAT(`links`) as "links" from `view_data_global` ');
            $q->execute();
            $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
    }

    $Example = new Example();

    $result = $Example->get_view_data();

    $result[0]["links"] = $Example->string_to_array($result[0]["links"]);

    echo json_encode($result);
```

This gives me the perfect object while
GROUP_CONCAT seems to be doing the trick this way, however I MUST know the column name that will contain multiple rows before writing the query. I am trying to figure out an approach for this and wish to make a custom query + code example that will transform cols with multiple rows of null null and not empty data into an array like above - but return the data.. again like the code above.

Below is an output of the actual data:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"This is the title test","links":["main","about","store"]}];
```

How can I replicate this process dynamically on each view table?

Thank you so much SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDOStatement::fetch` to retrieve your results, with `fetch_style` set to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` (some other values will also provide the same information). In this case, the result set will be array indexed by column name. You can access this information with `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for additional information.

Comment: This gives me `{"id":"1","title":"This is the title test","links":"main"};` not what I want because it does not contain the rest of the values for the links col. Any ideas. Thank you btw